# Python pandas: Identify route/path given by two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input file (csv-file) with data which has duplicate entries in the column `group` and might have duplicate entries in the column `size`.

A snippet with the data of just one group is given below. However, there are several groups in the real data file. So this is just a shortened and simplified example (`sample.csv`):

```
group,size,from,to
group32a4,0500,6sq2gp,m4qfce
group32a4,0800,oxlwtg,ru1u5r
group32a4,1200,rpziz0,oxlwtg
group32a4,1400,ru1u5r,fvvskj
group32a4,0500,m4qfce,60m2eq
group32a4,0050,fvvskj,6sq2gp
```

Since the data is coming from external software I am not able to change anything concerning the data format or data layout. So I need to import the data for further data handling and do the following tasks:

1. Keep one entry for each group, only. This entry must have the biggest value in the column `size`.
2. Get the path wich routes through the group and can be arranged from the columns `from` and `to`.

I decided to use `pandas` for data handling since the real data file is rather complex and I wanted to have the capability of its permormant features. However, if there are any other (more suitable) tools or approaches using other Python modules those would be totally fine and not a problem at all.

In order to accomplish the first task I did:

```
import pandas as pd

# open file and read data
with open('sample.csv') as f:
    data = pd.read_csv(f)

# sort descending by columns `group` and `size`
# sorting descending because `df.drop_duplicates()` keeps first element by default
df_sorted = data.sort_values(['group', 'size'], ascending=False)

# drop duplicates in order to keep first entry only
one_entry = df_sorted.drop_duplicates('group')

# print handled data
print(one_entry)
```

Which leads to the desired output:

```
       group  size    from      to
3  group32a4  1400  ru1u5r  fvvskj
```

So, I need to accomplish the second task. Since all of the above data handling was not done inplace I am able to access all stages of data throughout the data handling procedure.

Unfortunately, I do not have any idea about how to do that. I have some conceptual thoughts about how that could be done.
First of all I need to arrange the route out of each group subset. In the example given above that would result in:

```
rpziz0 --> oxlwtg --> ru1u5r --> fvvskj --> 6sq2gp --> m4qfce --> 60m2eq
```

After that I neet to extract source and destination and summarize the route like that:

```
rpziz0 --> 60m2eq
```

Which should result into this overall output:

```
       group  size    from      to
3  group32a4  1400  rpziz0  60m2eq
```

So the question I came up with is as follows:

How can I identifiy the route out of each subset which is defined by each `group` tag (using pandas' methods preferably)?

*Note: Using Python 3.4.3, Pandas 0.17.1*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and last [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html). Next group was added for better testing:

```
print df
        group  size    from      to
0   group32a4   500  6sq2gp  m4qfce
1   group32a4   800  oxlwtg  ru1u5r
2   group32a4  1200  rpziz0  oxlwtg
3   group32a4  1400  ru1u5r  fvvskj
4   group32a4   500  m4qfce  60m2eq
5   group32a4    50  fvvskj  6sq2gp
6   group13a4   500  6sq2gp  m4qfce
7   group13a4   800  oxlwtg  ru1u5r
8   group13a4  1200  rpziz0  oxlwtg
9   group13a4  1400  ru1u5r  fvvskj
10  group13a4   500  m4qfce  60m2eq
11  group13a4    50  fvvskj  6sq2gp

#set index and stack data - columns 'from' and 'to' to one column 'route'
df = df.set_index(['group', 'size']).stack().reset_index(name='route')
```

```
print df
        group  size level_2   route
0   group32a4   500    from  6sq2gp
1   group32a4   500      to  m4qfce
2   group32a4   800    from  oxlwtg
3   group32a4   800      to  ru1u5r
4   group32a4  1200    from  rpziz0
5   group32a4  1200      to  oxlwtg
6   group32a4  1400    from  ru1u5r
7   group32a4  1400      to  fvvskj
8   group32a4   500    from  m4qfce
9   group32a4   500      to  60m2eq
10  group32a4    50    from  fvvskj
11  group32a4    50      to  6sq2gp
12  group13a4   500    from  6sq2gp
13  group13a4   500      to  m4qfce
14  group13a4   800    from  oxlwtg
15  group13a4   800      to  ru1u5r
16  group13a4  1200    from  rpziz0
17  group13a4  1200      to  oxlwtg
18  group13a4  1400    from  ru1u5r
19  group13a4  1400      to  fvvskj
20  group13a4   500    from  m4qfce
21  group13a4   500      to  60m2eq
22  group13a4    50    from  fvvskj
23  group13a4    50      to  6sq2gp
```

```
def f(x):
    #set column size to max
    x['size'] =  x['size'].max()
    return x.drop_duplicates('route', keep=False)

#apply custom function f
df = df.groupby('group').apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
print df
       group  size level_2   route
0  group13a4  1400    from  rpziz0
1  group13a4  1400      to  60m2eq
2  group32a4  1400    from  rpziz0
3  group32a4  1400      to  60m2eq

#reshape data, remove column tmp
df = df.pivot(index='group', columns='level_2').reset_index()
df.columns = ['group','size','tmp','from', 'to']
df = df.drop('tmp', axis=1)
print df
       group  size    from      to
0  group13a4  1400  rpziz0  60m2eq
1  group32a4  1400  rpziz0  60m2eq
```

EDIT:

Similar, I think faster solution with filling DataFrame in [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) function `f` and [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html),  [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
def f(x):
    #get max of column size
    m = x['size'].max()
    #remove all duplicates - stay only one value from and one value to
    x = x.drop_duplicates('route', keep=False)
    x['group'] = x.iat[0, 0]
    x['size'] = m
    x['from'] = x.iat[0, 3]
    x['to'] = x.iat[1, 3]

    #print x
    #return first row and columns group, size from to
    #print x.iloc[0,[0,1,4,5]]
    return  x.iloc[0,[0,1,4,5]]

#apply custom function f
df = df.groupby('group').apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
print df
       group  size    from      to
0  group13a4  1400  rpziz0  60m2eq
1  group32a4  1400  rpziz0  60m2eq
```

Comment: You imported `io` to get a file-like object from the string containing the sample data. However, why do you import `numpy`? I did not see any usage of that, did I? Maybe I missed something...

Comment: Nunpy is not necessary.

Comment: I edit answer, because doesnt work with multiple groups.